# exception while using nativeJPQL delete Query

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I tried to delete using nativeQuery but I have this exсeption:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:403)
    ...................
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1668)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
...............
```

My Employe Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Employe implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String prenom;
    
    private String nom;
    
    private String email;
    
    private int isActif;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="employe", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    Contrat contrat;
    
    @ManyToMany( mappedBy="employes", fetch= FetchType.EAGER , cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Departement> departements;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE ,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    List<Mission> missions;
.........
```

My Department Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Departement implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne( cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} )
    private Entreprise entreprise;
    
    @OneToMany( mappedBy="departement", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Mission> missions;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Employe> employes;
```

My Service :

@Autowired
IEmployeRepository empRep;
......
@Override
public void deleteEmployerById(int id) {
Employe e = empRep.findById(id).orElse(null);
// remove all associations for this author
empRep.deleteEmployerDepartementsAssociations(id);
empRep.delete(e);
}

My EmployeRepository:

@Repository
public interface IEmployeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employe, Integer>{

```
 @Modifying
 @Query(value = "DELETE FROM departement_employes WHERE employes_id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
 void deleteEmployerDepartementsAssociations(@Param("id") int id );
```

}

Only the delete Query do not work , I am trying to delete all the departments that are associated with a certain employe.

The association for the employe and the departments is many to many bidirectional association.

I am trying to delete the associations before deleting the employe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to correct your query in this way:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM departement_employes WHERE employes_id = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteEmployerDepartementsAssociations(@Param("id") int id );
```

You have to wrap any database-modifying operation in a transaction. Look for example to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-transaction-required-exception).

So, as one of possible approaches you can annotate your service method by `@Transactional` annotation:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteEmployerById(int id) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: i edited like you told me but i have another exception , i will edit my question, the exception just changed

Comment: a new eception , i will edit my question again and with more details

Comment: why do you think i have exception?? the relation between employe and departement is many to many bidirectianal , i am not sure about the cascades or about the service that delete , mabe something is wrong there?

Comment: wow thank you so much ! it had worked , but the employe in the service after deleting the associations , it is not deleted any more in the database  , should i change cascade type in the entity?

Comment: It will not help. as you use native query for removing. And by the way for [@ManyToMany](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many) associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.